# Отображать начало текста во вкладке в PySide6

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6, pyqt6, qtabwidget

Нужно сделать так, чтобы всегда были видны первые символы вкладки, а последние уже могли бы скрываться. 
По умолчанию виден только центральный текст

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("QTabWidget")
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(QWidget(), "First Tab 11111111111")
        self.tab_widget.addTab(QWidget(), "Second Tab 2222222222")
        self.tab_widget.setStyleSheet("""
        QTabBar::tab {
                margin: 4px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                max-width: 100px;
                padding: 5px;
        }
        
        QTabBar::tab:selected {
                background: black;
                color: white;
        }""")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**elideMode**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#elideMode-prop) : [**Qt::TextElideMode**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextElideMode-enum)
>
> Как скрыть текст в панели вкладок
>
> Это свойство управляет тем, как исключаются элементы, когда для данного размера панели вкладок недостаточно места для их отображения.
>
> По умолчанию значение зависит от стиля.

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("QTabWidget")
        
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget(self)
# +++
        self.tab_widget.setElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)                     # +++     
        
        self.tab_widget.addTab(QWidget(), "First Tab 11111111111")
        self.tab_widget.addTab(QWidget(), "Second Tab 2222222222")
        self.tab_widget.setStyleSheet("""
            QTabBar::tab {
                    margin: 4px;
                    border-radius: 6px;
                    max-width: 100px;
                    padding: 5px;
            }
            QTabBar::tab:selected {
                    background: black;
                    color: white;
            }
        """)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]